# Как соединить элементы кортежа?

Tags: python, list, tuple

Есть кортеж:

```
('2020-08-02', '00:00', 'A', 'B', 'C')
```

Нужно соединить первый и второй элементы:

```
('2020-08-02 00:00', 'A', 'B', 'C')
```

Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: что значит "объединить индексы"?

Comment: В Python если что нет массивов, то что вы показали это кортеж

Comment: @MaxU, я сделал чуть по другому, но вы в любом случае помогли мне. Извините что сразу не отреагировал, работы много.

Comment: @MaxU вот ответ res = [(f"{i[0]} {i[1]}",) + i[2:] for i in data]

Comment: Т.е. у вас был список кортежей, а не один кортеж, как в примере?

Comment: @MaxU да, видимо я не дописал. Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Для Python 3.6+:

```
data = ('2020-08-02', '00:00', 'A', 'B', 'C')

res = (f"{data[0]} {data[1]}",) + data[2:]
```

---

результат:

```
In [121]: res
Out[121]: ('2020-08-02 00:00', 'A', 'B', 'C')
```